# Why do I get an error when choosing the initial loading page?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

When I select the initial component of the upload in my function module `GalleryModuleModule` this component `GalleryComponent`

I get this error:

> `Invalid configuration of route '': Array cannot be specified` (all components are in the `GalleryModuleModule`). Tell me what am I doing wrong and how to solve this problem?

**app.module:**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { GalleryModuleModule } from './gallery-module/gallery-module.module';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        GalleryModuleModule,
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

**app.component.html:**

```
<div class="container">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

**gallery-module.module:**

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {GalleryComponent} from "./gallery/gallery.component";
import {GalleryAddComponent} from './gallery/gallery-add/gallery-add.component';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from "@angular/router";

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {path: '', redirectTo: '/gallery', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path: 'gallery-add', component: 'GalleryAddComponent'},
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            appRoutes,
            {enableTracing: true}
        ])
    ],
    declarations: [GalleryComponent, GalleryAddComponent],
    exports: [GalleryComponent, GalleryAddComponent RouterModule],
})
export class GalleryModuleModule {
}
```

Comment: Try passing GalleryAddComponent instead of 'GalleryAddComponent' as 'gallery-add' path component.

Comment: Also it looks like you are redirecting to '/gallery' and you didn't define '/gallery' path yet. Add this route to prevent redirecting to non-existing path.

Comment: `{path: '', redirectTo: '/gallery', pathMatch: 'full'}, ` are you missing `/gallery` in routes. Add like this : `{path: 'gallery', component: GalleryComponent},`

Comment: Also don't add component with `string('')` like this : `component: 'GalleryAddComponent'`, just use without string like this : `component: GalleryAddComponent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did `{path: '', redirectTo: '/gallery', pathMatch: 'full'},` while in fact you dont have a path named `gallery` that should be redirected to.
For exemple changing your route configuration to:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {path: '', redirectTo: '/gallery', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path: 'gallery', component: GalleryComponent},
    {path: 'gallery-add', component: GalleryAddComponent},

];
```

and removing the extra array inside `RouterModule.forRoot()` (https://angular.io/api/router/RouterModule#forRoot) (as mentioned by @Suresh ) should work !

**PS**: do not forget to import the components listed in your route config (**they should not be quoted as strings**)

Comment: if i write  {path: '', redirectTo: '/GalleryAddComponent', pathMatch: 'full'} i have the same problem

Comment: @IgorShvets you redirect to the `path` value not `component`'s one, re-check my answer.

Comment: the problem did not dare, all my components are inside the "gallery-module.module" module, maybe something is wrong with the path?

Answer (score 0):

See, RouterModule.forRoot() needs to be defined only in App.module.ts which is the root router module. But you are defining those root routes in Your Child Module 'GalleryModuleModule' which is imported in to app.module.ts.

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {GalleryComponent} from "./gallery/gallery.component";
import {GalleryAddComponent} from './gallery/gallery-add/gallery-add.component';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from "@angular/router";

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {path: '', redirectTo: '/gallery', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path: 'gallery-add', component: 'GalleryAddComponent'},
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(
            appRoutes,
            {enableTracing: true}
        )
    ],
    declarations: [GalleryComponent, GalleryAddComponent],
    exports: [GalleryComponent, GalleryAddComponent RouterModule],
})
export class GalleryModuleModule {
}
```

Comment: I got the issue. You need to remove array inside forRoot() method.

Comment: should fix your appRoutes config also.